# Angular 8 set input validation based on dropdown chose

Tags: angular, validation, angular8

I'm new to Angular and find it quite tricky with this validation concept. 
But I have been looking around the internet and I can't seem to find the answer for my problem. Although there is a lot of good tips and guides about validation for Angular.

So my problem is that I have an dropdown menu with 6 options which user can select. After a user has selected one option I want an input field to change validation. For an example:

If the user select option 1 in the drop down. I want the input field to have the validation required and maximum length 5 tokens.

If the user select option 2 in the drop down. I want the input field to have the validation required and
maximum length of 10 tokens.

If the user chose option 6 in the drop down. I want the input field to be disabled with no validation.
(If the use chose this option then the validation formgroup should be valid)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

The answer in [Angular dropdown validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346013/angular-dropdown-validation) does not cover changing validation on the input element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular dropdown validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346013/angular-dropdown-validation)

Comment: @MEDZ not quite. It was missing subscription on the dropdown meny. So I could change validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`valueChanges`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges), [`setValidators()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators) and [`clearValidators()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges).

First you need to subscribe to each value change of the dropdown menu using `valueChanges` of the form control. The subscription will emit the new value of the dropdown and with the new value you need to run your logic to decide the validation you need to apply. After that you can use the `setValidators()` method to set validation for the form control of the input field. If you need to remove the validation you can use the `clearValidators()` method. You can enable or disable a field using `disable()` and `enable()` methods on the form control.

Example:

```
field1.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
  if (val === 'a') {
    field2.setValidators([Validators.minLength(1)]);
  } else {
    field2.clearValidators();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! yes, subscribing to the dropdown meny fixed it.